# Checkmarx Improper Resource Access Authorization

Tags: java, sql, database, authorization, checkmarx

I am using the Checkmarx security tool to scan my code, it is saying that when I execute executeUpdate() commands to the database that is "Improper Resource Access Authorization."

Various Googling with no success.

```java
int rowInserted = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you know what **Improper Resource Access Authorization** is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some code that performs access control checks that makes use of words like "*admin*", "*authoriz*" or "*allowed*"

```
 if (user.equals("admin")){
    int rowInserted = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
 }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, Checkmarks is warning `cst = conect.prepareCall(ConstantesDAO.FNFA_REFS); .... cst.setString(3, params.get("cycleId")); ..... Just here -> cst.execute();` :( I tried your suggestion but does not work.

Comment: I don't see any validation check for access control in the code snippet you shared

Comment: @securecodeninja tried your solution. but didnt work `if(user.equals("admin")) {String endPoint=prop.getProperty("endpoint");}`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a method to your class:

```
private static boolean checkAuthorization(String userName) {
    return userName.equals("authorization");
}
```

and check your string with:

```
if (checkAuthorization("authorization")) {
    int rowInserted = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```