# Improper Resource Access Authorization in JPA repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, repository, checkmarx

I have below JPA repository code :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="attributes",itemResourceRel="attribute",excerptProjection=AttributeHeaderProjection.class,exported = false)
public interface AttributeHeaderDataRestRepository extends JpaRepository<AttributeHeader, String> {

    @Query(" SELECT HDR FROM AttributeHeader HDR, AttributeObject OBJ "
            + "WHERE HDR.attribute=OBJ.attribute "
            + " AND OBJ.objName= ?1 ")
    List<AttributeHeader> byName( String name);
}
```

I am getting

> "Improper Resource Access Authorization"

CheckMarx issue for the above code.

How to resolve this types of CheckMarx issue?

Comment: see my answer here that is related to your question. you need to add some form of access control check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824178/checkmarx-improper-resource-access-authorization/57863422#57863422. Please upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Could you please remove @RepositoryRestResource from repository level and make it as normal jpa repository that might work.

Comment: this won't help.