# SAST Issue - Improper Resource Access Authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, checkmarx, secure-coding, sast

I am using Checkmarx security tool to scan my code. It is throwing Improper Resource Access Authorization error in the repository.

```
@Query(value="select * from mapping_table where project_id = :projectId", nativeQuery=true)
List<MappingTable>  findByProjectId(@Param(PROJECT_ID) String projectId);
```

Comment: please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824178/checkmarx-improper-resource-access-authorization

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response. We are using crud repository. Where to place this validation in Spring Restful API.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the ask but isn't validations possible like the one mentioned here https://phoenixnap.com/kb/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services#ftoc-heading-2