# Improper Resource Access Authorization error in checkmarx when reading a property

Tags: java, owasp, checkmarx, checkmark

Checkmarx report is showing `Improper Resource Access Authorization` for the following line.

```
String endPoint=prop.getProperty("endpoint");
```

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57863422/3343195) answer, I have added access control check before reading the property. But checkmarx report is still showing the error.

```
String user="admin";
if(user.equals("admin")) {
    String endPoint=prop.getProperty("endpoint");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue like this

```
 String endPoint=(String)prop.getOrDefault("endpoint", null );
```